# Sampling sites map in R

Tags: r, spatial

For my project 60 sampling sites were sampled in Betty's Bay MPA on the South African Coast. These sites are at different depths and represent different habitats.
I am very new to programming spatial data so I really appreciate any help.

I tried to follow the code from this page: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/10/make-a-map-of-your-study-site-with-tmap

And everything works up to the point when I want to plot the map, then the error says:
Error: Object Coastline is neither from class sf, stars, Spatial, Raster, nor SpatRaster.

Where the code says
`land <- st_read(dsn ="LandPoly")`
I coded
`Coastline <- st_read(dsn ="RSAProvinces") Coastline <- st_is_valid(Coastline, NA_on_exception = TRUE, reason = FALSE)` .
RSA Provinces is a shapefile I downloaded online.

What I hope for is a map of my study area with the borders of the MPA (which I have a shapefile for) and the sampling sites with a color gradient for the depths (light blue to dark blue the deeper it gets) and different shapes for the three different habitats.
I tried with ggplot and the map "world" for the coastline but my area is so small that it's not detailed enough.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess `st_as_sf()` will solve the problem, however, could you provide the link to the shapefile? Then it's easier to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I just realized it's a problem with the shapefile. I got it from https://africaopendata.org/group/fc691a3f-cfce-46d6-93a0-77bdccfec89d?tags=gis&res_format=SHP but r says it's an empty string. Any advice on where to download a proper shapefile for the Western Cape Province?

Comment: Also when I try  `Coastline <- st_as_sf(Coastline)` than the output is an error:
Error in UseMethod("st_as_sf") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_as_sf' applied to an object of class "logical"

Comment: which of the datasets did you take?

Comment: From the "Department of Agriculture, Fisheries and Forestry - South African Environmental GIS Data" folder I downloaded and tried various datasets such as the Biomes one

Answer (score 0):

Using the Biomes data set you can do the following

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

df <- st_read("RSA_biome.shp")

df %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = BIOME), lwd = 0) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3")
```

and you will receive
[image]

Of course you can also filter for a specific region as defined in the BIOME column before plotting e.g.

```
df %>% 
  filter(BIOME == "Fynbos") %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = BIOME), lwd = 0) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3")
```

[image]